# Confluent Generalized S3 Source connector (silent failure)

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Running into strange issue with Generalized S3 source connector running on confluent platform. Not able to pin point where exactly the error is or what the root cause is :

The only error I see in the ssh console is this (related to logs) :

```
[2023-02-11 11:12:45,464] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster-1] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1709)
log4j:ERROR A "io.confluent.log4j.redactor.RedactorAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by
log4j:ERROR [PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/share/java/source-2.5.1/}] whereas object of type
log4j:ERROR "io.confluent.log4j.redactor.RedactorAppender" was loaded by [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "redactor".
[2023-02-11 11:13:35,741] INFO Injecting Confluent license properties into connector '<unspecified>' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfigDecorator:412)
[2023-02-11 11:13:44,001] INFO Injecting Confluent license properties into connector 'S3GenConnectorConnector_7' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfigDecorator:412)
[2023-02-11 11:13:44,006] INFO S3SourceConnectorConfig values:
        aws.access.key.id = <<ACCESS KEY HERE>>
        aws.secret.access.key = [hidden]
        behavior.on.error = fail
        bucket.listing.max.objects.threshold = -1
        confluent.license = [hidden]
        confluent.topic = _confluent-command
        confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers = [172.27.157.66:9092]
        confluent.topic.replication.factor = 3
        directory.delim = /
        file.discovery.starting.timestamp = 0
        filename.regex = (.+)\+(\d+)\+.+$
        folders = []
        format.bytearray.extension = .bin
        format.bytearray.separator =
        format.class = class io.confluent.connect.s3.format.string.StringFormat
        format.json.schema.enable = false
        mode = RESTORE_BACKUP
        parse.error.topic.prefix = error
        partition.field.name = []
        partitioner.class = class io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
        path.format =
        record.batch.max.size = 200
        s3.bucket.name = mytestbucketamtk
        s3.credentials.provider.class = class com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
        s3.http.send.expect.continue = true
        s3.part.retries = 3
        s3.path.style.access = true
        s3.poll.interval.ms = 60000
        s3.proxy.password = null
        s3.proxy.url =
        s3.proxy.username = null
        s3.region = us-east-1
        s3.retry.backoff.ms = 200
        s3.sse.customer.key = null
        s3.ssea.name =
        s3.wan.mode = false
        schema.cache.size = 50
        store.url = null
        task.batch.size = 10
        topic.regex.list = [first_topic:.*]
        topics.dir = topics
 (io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnectorConfig:376)
[2023-02-11 11:13:44,029] INFO Using configured AWS access key credentials instead of configured credentials provider class. (io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3Storage:500)
```

Connector Config file below :

```
{
  "name": "S3GenConnectorConnector_7",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "mode": "RESTORE_BACKUP",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.string.StringFormat",
    "s3.bucket.name": "mytestbucketamtk",
    "s3.region": "us-east-1",
    "aws.access.key.id": <<ACCESS KEY HERE>>,
    "aws.secret.access.key": <<SECRET KEY>>,
    "topic.regex.list":"first_topic:.*"
  }
}
```

The tasks are not getting created. And also no other errors in the connect console. The connect cluster is running on confluent platform.  Any pointers in right direction would be appreciated. Did I miss any required configuration ?

Comment: Look at the output from /status API

Comment: If you meant the rest api like this url ...:  http://localhost:8083/connectors/?expand=status , nothing fruitful there..........  {"S3GenConnectorConnector_7":{"status":{"name":"S3GenConnectorConnector_7","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"127.0.1.1:8083"},"tasks":[],"type":"source"}}}

Comment: Looks like you have some log4j errors? You can try removing that redactor class, then edit logging level to debug or higher

Comment: Any useful link to do that ? This link doesn't give the option to edit logging level. https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-source/current/configuration_options.html#amazon-s3-source-connector-configuration-properties

Comment: The plugin classloader and jdk class loader seem to be in conflict. Which are the values of the java.ext.dirs system property of your jvm? Does it include /usr/share/java? Take a look at the Class-Path property of your plugin jar manifest (location /usr/share/java/source-2.5.1).

Comment: java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
        /usr/lib/jni
        /lib
        /usr/lib                  Plugin path is the one you mentioned /usr/share/java . Can this error be because I am using Java 17 ?

Comment: `connect-log4j.properties` exists on your hard-drive; it's not a connector property. You can look at the source of `connect-distributed.sh` to find the approximate location on disk